# How does Teamcity builds the folder path for the tools it uses?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

**Context:**

I have installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015, version number 14.0.xxx.
They are installed under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0
```

however, Teamcity looks for it under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0
```

(because, I assume, it is getting this number from the MSBuild version).

**Question:**

Can I configure the folder where Teamcity will look for configuration files / executables somewhere?

Comment: What's the runner type of your build step? MSBuild? Visual Studio?

Comment: I am using MSBuild.

Comment: So what's the reasoning behind having the v14 tools installed in the v10.0 folder?

Comment: I'm not sure how they ended up there. I would like to tell TC where to look for them, but perhaps I should reinstall them under the recommended folder.